# split-quaternion rotation

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry, quaternions, hypercomplex-numbers

So, I learn about rotation basic quaternion, and now I am trying to understand split-quaternion and their rotation. 
As far as I understand, there are different formula, like $q=N(cosh(a)+psinh(a))$. As far as I understand(again), I can ignore N if I take p as $(0;0;1)$ or similar. 
Does rotation of split-quaternion is the same as simple quaternion? Like, $qwq^-1$? And what about different types of split-quaternions?

If you can, please give some examples. I am bad at understanding without examples, just by basic formula for each situation...
Thank you!

Comment: Split quaternions are just $2$-by-$2$ matrices, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to give some ideas on your question: It is well-known that rotations in Euclidean 3-space ($\mathbb{R}^3$) can be expressed by using unit-quaternions. A similar fact works for split-quaternions but in Lorentz-Minkowski 3-space ($\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$) which is defined as a real vector space with Lorentzian inner product:
$$ \langle u,v\rangle_L=-u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3\quad u=(u_1,u_2,u_3),v=(v_1,v_2,v_3). $$
In this space, the vectors are characterized by Lorentzian inner product. For a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$, the vector $v$ is said to be a spacelike if $\langle v, v\rangle_L>0$ or $v=0$, timelike if $\langle v, v\rangle_L<0$, lightlike (or null) if $\langle v, v\rangle_L=0$.

I don't mention all definitions on split quaternions assuming that you already know. A split quaternion $q=q_0+q_1i+q_2j+q_3k$ can be expressed as  $q=S_{q}+{\mathbf{V}_{q}},$ where $%
S_{q}=q_{0}$ and $\mathbf{V}_{q}=q_{1}i+q_{2}j+q_{3}k$ are called the scalar part and
vector part of $q$, respectively. Taking a split quaternion $q=q_0+q_1i+q_2j+q_3k$, we have that $I_q:=q\ast \bar{q}=\bar{q}\ast q=q_{0}^{2}+q_{1}^{2}-q_{2}^{2}-q_{3}^{2}$, where $\ast$ denotes the split-quaternion multiplication and $\bar{q}$ is the conjugate of $q$. A split quaternion $q$ is said to be spacelike, timelike or lightlike, if $I_{q}<0,I_{q}>0$ and $I_{q}=0,$ respectively. As you said, every split-quaternion has a polar form. For example, every timelike split quaternion with the spacelike vector part can be expressed as
    \begin{equation*}
  q=N_q(\cosh \theta +\eta\sinh \theta),
 \end{equation*}
    where $\cosh\theta=\dfrac{q_0}{N_q}$, $\sinh\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt{-q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2}}{N_q}$, $\eta=\dfrac{q_1i+q_2j+q_3k}{\sqrt{-q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2}}$ is a unit spacelike vector in $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$ and $\eta\ast \eta=1$.

After some basic facts, I would say that "Any rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$ can be stated with the aid of a unit timelike split quaternion."

We denote the set of all timelike split quaternions by
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbb{T}\mathbb{H}'=\{q=(q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)\in\mathbb{H}'|q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3\in \mathbb{R}, I_q>0\}.
\end{equation*}
which forms a group under the split quaternion product.
Consider the map $\phi$ for $q\in\mathbb{H}'$ unit split quaternion defined by 
\begin{equation*}
 \phi:\mathbb{R}^{1,2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{1,2}; \quad \phi(\mathbf{x})=q\ast \mathbf{x} \ast q^{-1}, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{1,2}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, if $q=(q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3)$ is a unit timelike split quaternion, the corresponding rotation matrix can be expressed as 
\begin{equation}
 M_q =\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  q_{0}^{2}+q_{1}^{2}+q_{2}^{2}+q_{3}^{2} & 2q_{3}q_{0}-2q_{1}q_{2} & 
  -2q_{0}q_{2}-2q_{1}q_{3} \\ 
  2q_{1}q_{2}+2q_{3}q_{0} & q_{0}^{2}-q_{1}^{2}-q_{2}^{2}+q_{3}^{2} & 
  -2q_{2}q_{3}-2q_{1}q_{0} \\ 
  2q_{1}q_{3}-2q_{1}q_{0} & 2q_{1}q_{0}-2q_{2}q_{3} & 
  q_{0}^{2}-q_{1}^{2}+q_{2}^{2}-q_{3}^{2}
 \end{array}
 \right].
\end{equation}

I know it is a long answer! If you have still confusing let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and answering this question! 

But it's still a bit complicated to me. 
Can you give me any examples of doing this stuff? 
I mean, this is pretty understandable in theory, like quaternion itself, but it's not intuitively to use is after you know everything about them. 
I mean, can we just take q as $q=(0;0;0;1)$, like we can do it with quaternions, and go for $N=1$, so this will be timelike. And, as far as I assume, $cosh(a)=0$, sinh(a)=1, and $n=1k$. Right? 
And as far as I understand, I can do regular multiplication without matrix, like quaternions?

Comment: @Gin $q=(0; 0; 0; 1)$ is not a timelike split quaternion since $I_q<0$. And $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$ $\cosh(a)\neq0$. For example, Take $q=(\sqrt{3}/2;1/2;0;0)$ which is a unit timelike split quaternion with timelike vector part that is, it can be written as $q=N_q(\cos\theta+\eta\sin\theta)$. You can simply calculate the rotation matrix. So, you'll see that $q$ corresponds to a rotation through $120^\circ$ about the timelike axis $(1,0,0)$.